# android: How can i set backpress on TabActivity ? where one tab contain only two activity?

Tags: android, tabs, activitygroup

- I am try to call my OffersActivity  to on backpress of offerDetails
  Activity.(I am using ActivityGroup and TabActivity).
- I am getting error to ArrayIndexOutOFBound...last two i am try to
  this to complete but it not done by me..guide me ..to solve this
  problem.in this when i run first tab is OffersActivity is open List
  when i clicked list item open its Details View
  (OfferDetailsActivity)and press Back it give error force close..

  i am Applied this example :- http://www.jtben.com/document/695851

  but it give the error `05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:406)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.wae.saterra.view.OffersActivity.back(OffersActivity.java:149)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.wae.saterra.view.OffersActivity.onBackPressed(OffersActivity.java:173)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1888)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2068)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchKeyEvent(TabHost.java:275)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
  05-15 10:35:00.755: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

  My Code :

  - TabActivity

    ```
    '
    ```

    extends TabActivity {
            TabHost tabHost;

    ```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sattera_tab_activity);
            tabHost = getTabHost();
            init();

        }

        private void init() {
            Intent intent;
            intent=new Intent().setClass(this, OffersActivity.class);
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("OffersActivity")
                    .setIndicator("OffersActivity",
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_prominent))
                    .setContent(intent));



    //      tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(null)
    //              .setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_prominent))
    //              .setContent(new Intent(this,OffersActivity.class)));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(null)
                    .setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_products))
                    .setContent(new Intent(this,ProductsActivity.class)));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(null)
                    .setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_service_ol))
                    .setContent(new Intent(this,ServiceActivity.class)));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(null)
                    .setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tenda_ol))
                    .setContent(new Intent(this,TendaOLActivity.class)));
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(null)
                    .setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_notify))
                    .setContent(new Intent(this,ContactUsActivity.class)));
            //int currentTab = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(OffersActivity.TAB_ID);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    //      Intent intent;
    //      intent=new Intent().setClass(this, OffersActivity.class);
    //      tabHost.addTab(tabHost
    //              .newTabSpec(null)
    //              .setIndicator(null,
    //                      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_prominent))
    //              .setContent(intent));
    //      intent=new Intent().setClass(this, ProductsActivity.class);
    //      tabHost.addTab(tabHost
    //              .newTabSpec(null)
    //              .setIndicator(null,
    //                      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_products))
    //              .setContent(intent));
    //      intent=new Intent().setClass(this, ServiceActivity.class);
    //      tabHost.addTab(tabHost
    //              .newTabSpec(null)
    //              .setIndicator(null,
    //                      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_service_ol))
    //              .setContent(intent));
    //      intent=new Intent().setClass(this, TendaOLActivity.class);
    //      tabHost.addTab(tabHost
    //              .newTabSpec(null)
    //              .setIndicator(null,
    //                      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tenda_ol))
    //              .setContent(intent));
    //      intent=new Intent().setClass(this, ContactUsActivity.class);
    //      tabHost.addTab(tabHost
    //              .newTabSpec(null)
    //              .setIndicator(null,
    //                      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_notify))
    //              .setContent(intent));
    //
    //      tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    //
    ```

    }

  }'
- 1) OffersActivity

  ```
  'public class OffersActivity extends ActivityGroup implements
      OnItemClickListener {

  CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
  ListView lvProducts;
  ArrayList<Products> productObj;
  Products product;
  public static OffersActivity group;

  private ArrayList<View> history;

  // View rootView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.product_list);

      this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
      group = this;

      init();
      // hideFB();
      // hideTwitter();
      setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_offer));
      // API Call

      if (Global.isNetworkAvailable(OffersActivity.this)) {
          new ProductAsyncTask().execute(Constants.url);
      } else {
          Intent intent = new Intent(OffersActivity.this,
                  OfflineActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);

          // AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
          // this);
          //
          // // set title
          // alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("No Internet Connection Available  ");
          //
          // // set dialog message
          // alertDialogBuilder
          // .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
          // .setCancelable(false)
          // .setPositiveButton("Yes",
          // new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          // public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
          // int id) {
          // Intent intent = new Intent(
          // OffersActivity.this,
          // OffersActivity.class);
          // startActivity(intent);
          //
          // }
          // });
          //
          // AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
          // // show it
          // alertDialog.show();
      }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if (adapter != null) {
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  }

  private void init() {
      productObj = new ArrayList<Products>();
      lvProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_products);
      lvProducts.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


          Intent intent = new Intent(OffersActivity.this,
                  OffersDetailActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("product", (Products) productObj.get(position));
          // startActivity(intent);

          View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("OffersDetailActivity",
                  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
          replaceView(view);

      }

      public void loadData() {
          adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(OffersActivity.this,
                  R.layout.product_list_row, productObj);

          lvProducts.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      protected void back() {

          if(history.size() > 0) {  
              history.remove(history.size());  
              setContentView(history.get(history.size()));  
          }else {  
              finish();  
          }   

      }

      protected void replaceView(View view) {
  //      if (history.size() == 0) {
  //          if (rootView != null) {
  //              history.add(rootView);
  //              rootView = null;
  //          }
  //      }
          // Adds the old one to history
          history.add(view);
          // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
          setContentView(view);

      }

      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
          OffersActivity.group.back();
          return;
      }

      public class ProductAsyncTask extends
              AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Products>> {

          String responseString = null;
          ProgressDialog progressDialog;

          public ProductAsyncTask() {
              super();
              progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OffersActivity.this);
              progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
              progressDialog.show();
          }

          @Override
          protected ArrayList<Products> doInBackground(String... params) {

              responseString = readJSONSFeed(params[0]);
              if (responseString != null) {
                  return processUserListJSON(responseString);
              } else {
                  return null;
              }
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Products> result) {
              super.onPostExecute(result);
              if (result.size() == 0 || result == null) {
              }
              progressDialog.dismiss();
              loadData();

          }

          private String readJSONSFeed(String url) {

              StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

              HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + Constants.REQ_FOR_OFFER);



              try {
                  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                  StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                  int statuscode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                  if (statuscode == 200) {
                      HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                      InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                      String line = null;
                      if ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                          stringBuilder.append(line);
                      }
                      // buffer.close();
                      inputStream.close();
                  } else {
                  }

              } catch (Exception e) {
              }
              return stringBuilder.toString();
          }

          private synchronized ArrayList<Products> processUserListJSON(
                  String response) {

              try {
                  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                  JSONArray Records = json
                          .getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_OBJECT_DATA);
                  for (int i = 0; i < Records.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject Record = Records.getJSONObject(i);

                      String tProductID = Record.getString("product_id");
                      String tTitle = Record.getString("title");
                      String tImage = Record.getString("image");
                      String tDetails = Record.getString("short_description");
                      String tLongDetails = Record.getString("long_description");
                      String tOffer = Record.getString("offer");
                      String tActive = Record.getString("active");
                      String tPromoText = Record.getString("promotion_text");
                      String tProminent = Record.getString("prominent");

                      product = new Products(tProductID, tTitle, tDetails,
                              tLongDetails, tImage, tOffer, tActive, tPromoText,
                              tProminent);

                      if (product == null) {
                      } else {
                          productObj.add(product);
                      }

                  }

              } catch (JSONException ex) {
                  System.out.println(ex);
                  return null;
              }

              return productObj;
          }

      }

  }'
  ```
- OfferDeatilsActivity

  '
  public class OffersDetailActivity extends Activity implements
          OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
      Gallery gallery;
      TextView prod_descri, productTitle1, productTitle2;
      ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
      ImageView leftArrow, rightArrow;
      private int selectedImagePosition = 0;
      private List drawables;
      String title, url, title1;
      Bundle b;
      Products product;
      ProductDetails pDetails;
      ArrayList productList;
      Button btnFacebook, btnTwitter;

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.products_details);
      init();
      setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_offer));
      b = getIntent().getExtras();
      product = (Products) b.getSerializable("product");
      if (b != null) {
          if (Global.isNetworkAvailable(OffersDetailActivity.this)) {
              new ProductAsyncTask().execute(Constants.url,
                      product.product_id);
          } else {

              Intent intent = new Intent(OffersDetailActivity.this,
                      OfflineActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
      } else {
      }
  }
  ```

  //  @Override
  //  public void onBackPressed() {
  //      OffersActivity.group.back();
  //      // super.onBackPressed();
  //
  //  }

  ```
  private void init() {
      productList = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>();
      gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.product_gallery);
      prod_descri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
      productTitle1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productTitle1);
      productTitle2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productTitle2);

      leftArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
      rightArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);

      btnFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFB);
      btnFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTwitter);
      //btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
      // btnTwitter.setOnClickListener(this);

      leftArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
      rightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
      gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.left_arrow_imageview:

          if (selectedImagePosition > 0) {

              // leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              --selectedImagePosition;
          } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {
              leftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);

          break;
      case R.id.right_arrow_imageview:
          if (selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {
              // rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              ++selectedImagePosition;
          } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {
              rightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }

          gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);

          break;



      default:
          break;
      }

  }

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
          long id) {

      selectedImagePosition = position;

      productTitle1.setText(product.title);
      productTitle2.setText(productList.get(position).title);
      prod_descri.setText(productList.get(position).description);

      if (selectedImagePosition > 0
              && selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {
          leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {
          leftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {
          rightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      // setSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  }

  // AsyncTask

  public class ProductAsyncTask extends
          AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<ProductDetails>> {

      private Context getDialogContext() {
          Context context;
          if (getParent() != null)
              context = getParent();
          else
              context = OffersDetailActivity.this;
          return context;
      }

      String responseString = null;
      ProgressDialog progressDialog;

      public ProductAsyncTask() {
          super();
          // progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductDetailsActivity.this);
          progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getDialogContext());
          progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          super.onPreExecute();
          progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
          progressDialog.show();
      }

      @Override
      protected ArrayList<ProductDetails> doInBackground(String... params) {

          responseString = readJSONSFeed(params[0], params[1]);

          if (responseString != null) {
              return processProductDetailsJSON(responseString);
          } else {
              return null;
          }
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProductDetails> result) {
          super.onPostExecute(result);
          if (result.size() == 0 || result == null) {
          }
          progressDialog.dismiss();

          drawables = createDrawables(result);
          imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(OffersDetailActivity.this,
                  drawables);
          if (drawables.size() > 0) {

              gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);
          }

          if (drawables.size() == 1) {
              leftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              rightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }

          gallery.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

      }

      private List<Drawable> createDrawables(ArrayList<ProductDetails> result) {

          List<Drawable> drawablesUrl = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
          try {
              for (ProductDetails objProDetails : result) {
                  drawablesUrl.add(Global
                          .getBitmapFromURL(objProDetails.image_path));
                  // drawablesUrl.add(loadImageFromURL(objProDetails.image_path));
              }
              return drawablesUrl;

          } catch (Exception e) {
              return null;
          }

      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      private Drawable loadImageFromURL(String image_path) {
          try {
              InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
              Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
              return d;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              return null;
          }
      }

      private String readJSONSFeed(String url, String productID) {

          StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + Constants.REQ_FOR_PRODUCT_IMAGE
                  + productID + Constants.REQ_FOR_OFFER);



          try {
              HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
              StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

              int statuscode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

              if (statuscode == 200) {

                  HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                  InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                  String line = null;
                  if ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                      stringBuilder.append(line);
                  }
                  // buffer.close();
                  inputStream.close();
              } else {
              }

          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          return stringBuilder.toString();
      }

      private synchronized ArrayList<ProductDetails> processProductDetailsJSON(
              String response) {

          try {
              JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
              JSONArray Records = json
                      .getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_OBJECT_DATA);
              for (int i = 0; i < Records.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject Record = Records.getJSONObject(i);

                  String tTitle = Record.getString("title");
                  String tImagePath = Record.getString("image_path");
                  String tDescription = Record.getString("description");

                  pDetails = new ProductDetails(tDescription, tTitle,
                          tImagePath);

                  if (pDetails == null) {
                      Log.v("SATERRA", "product object null");
                  } else {
                      productList.add(pDetails);
                      Log.v("SATERRA", "product details title ="
                              + productList.get(i).title);
                  }
              }

          } catch (JSONException ex) {
              System.out.println(ex);
              return null;
          }

          return productList;
      }

  }
  ```

  }'

  - I am getting error to ArrayIndexOutOFBound...last two i am try to this to complete but it not done by me..guide me ..to solve this problem.in this when i run first tab is OffersActivity is open List when i clicked list item open its Details View (OfferDetailsActivity)and press Back it give error force close..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
         - this solve ...use this Code..
    1)OffersActivityGroup  add one Activity to add your root activity...

        public class OffersActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

            public static OffersActivityGroup group;
            private ArrayList<View> history;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
                group = this;

                // Start the root activity withing the group and get its view
                View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(
                        "OffersActivity",
                        new Intent(this, OffersActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                        .getDecorView();

                // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
                replaceView(view);

            }

            public void replaceView(View v) {
                // Adds the old one to history
                history.add(v);
                // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
                setContentView(v);
            }

            public void back() {
                if (history.size() > 0) {
                    history.remove(history.size() - 1);
                    setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                OffersActivityGroup.group.back();
                return;
            }

        }


    2)OffersActivity

        public class OffersActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

        CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
        ListView lvProducts;
        ArrayList<Products> productObj;
        Products product;

        // View rootView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.product_list);

            init();

            // hideFB();
            // hideTwitter();
            setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_offer));
            // API Call

            if (Global.isNetworkAvailable(OffersActivity.this)) {
                new ProductAsyncTask().execute(Constants.url);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(OffersActivity.this,
                        OfflineActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        private void init() {
            productObj = new ArrayList<Products>();
            lvProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_products);
            lvProducts.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(OffersActivity.this,
                    OffersDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("product", (Products) productObj.get(position));


            View view = OffersActivityGroup.group
                    .getLocalActivityManager()
                    .startActivity("OffersDetailActivity",
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                    .getDecorView();
            OffersActivityGroup.group.replaceView(view);

        }

        public void loadData() {
            adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(OffersActivity.this,
                    R.layout.product_list_row, productObj);

            lvProducts.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        // @Override
        // public void onBackPressed() {
        // OffersActivity.group.back();
        // return;
        // }

        public class ProductAsyncTask extends
                AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Products>> {

            String responseString = null;
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            public ProductAsyncTask() {
                super();
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<Products> doInBackground(String... params) {

                responseString = readJSONSFeed(params[0]);
                if (responseString != null) {
                    return processUserListJSON(responseString);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Products> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (result.size() == 0 || result == null) {
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                loadData();

            }

            private String readJSONSFeed(String url) {

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + Constants.REQ_FOR_OFFER);



                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                    int statuscode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                    if (statuscode == 200) {
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                        String line = null;
                        if ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(line);
                        }
                        // buffer.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                    } else {
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }

            private synchronized ArrayList<Products> processUserListJSON(
                    String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray Records = json
                            .getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_OBJECT_DATA);
                    for (int i = 0; i < Records.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject Record = Records.getJSONObject(i);

                        String tProductID = Record.getString("product_id");
                        String tTitle = Record.getString("title");
                        String tImage = Record.getString("image");
                        String tDetails = Record.getString("short_description");
                        String tLongDetails = Record.getString("long_description");
                        String tOffer = Record.getString("offer");
                        String tActive = Record.getString("active");
                        String tPromoText = Record.getString("promotion_text");
                        String tProminent = Record.getString("prominent");

                        product = new Products(tProductID, tTitle, tDetails,
                                tLongDetails, tImage, tOffer, tActive, tPromoText,
                                tProminent);

                        if (product == null) {
                        } else {
                            productObj.add(product);
                        }

                    }

                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                    return null;
                }

                return productObj;
            }

        }

    }
2)OfferDetailsActivity

    public class OffersDetailActivity extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
    Gallery gallery;
    TextView prod_descri, productTitle1, productTitle2;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    ImageView leftArrow, rightArrow;
    private int selectedImagePosition = 0;
    private List<Drawable> drawables;
    String title, url, title1;
    Bundle b;
    Products product;
    ProductDetails pDetails;
    ArrayList<ProductDetails> productList;
    Button btnFacebook, btnTwitter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.products_details);
        init();
        setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_offer));
        b = getIntent().getExtras();
        product = (Products) b.getSerializable("product");
        if (b != null) {
            if (Global.isNetworkAvailable(OffersDetailActivity.this)) {
                new ProductAsyncTask().execute(Constants.url,
                        product.product_id);
            } else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(OffersDetailActivity.this,
                        OfflineActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
        }
    }

//  @Override
//  public void onBackPressed() {
//      OffersActivity.group.back();
//      // super.onBackPressed();
//
//  }

    private void init() {
        productList = new ArrayList<ProductDetails>();
        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.product_gallery);
        prod_descri = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
        productTitle1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productTitle1);
        productTitle2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.productTitle2);

        leftArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_imageview);
        rightArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right_arrow_imageview);

        btnFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFB);
        btnFacebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTwitter);
        //btnFacebook.setOnClickListener(this);
        // btnTwitter.setOnClickListener(this);

        leftArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        rightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.left_arrow_imageview:

            if (selectedImagePosition > 0) {
                // leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                --selectedImagePosition;
            } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {
                leftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);

            break;
        case R.id.right_arrow_imageview:
            if (selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {
                // rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ++selectedImagePosition;
            } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {
                rightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);

            break;



        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        selectedImagePosition = position;

        productTitle1.setText(product.title);
        productTitle2.setText(productList.get(position).title);
        prod_descri.setText(productList.get(position).description);

        if (selectedImagePosition > 0
                && selectedImagePosition < drawables.size() - 1) {
            leftArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rightArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (selectedImagePosition == 0) {
            leftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (selectedImagePosition == drawables.size() - 1) {
            rightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // setSelectedImage(selectedImagePosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

    // AsyncTask

    public class ProductAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<ProductDetails>> {

        private Context getDialogContext() {
            Context context;
            if (getParent() != null)
                context = getParent();
            else
                context = OffersDetailActivity.this;
            return context;
        }

        String responseString = null;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public ProductAsyncTask() {
            super();
            // progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProductDetailsActivity.this);
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getDialogContext());
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ProductDetails> doInBackground(String... params) {

            responseString = readJSONSFeed(params[0], params[1]);

            if (responseString != null) {
                return processProductDetailsJSON(responseString);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProductDetails> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result.size() == 0 || result == null) {
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            drawables = createDrawables(result);
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(OffersDetailActivity.this,
                    drawables);
            if (drawables.size() > 0) {

                gallery.setSelection(selectedImagePosition, true);
            }

            if (drawables.size() == 1) {
                leftArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rightArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            gallery.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

        }

        private List<Drawable> createDrawables(ArrayList<ProductDetails> result) {

            List<Drawable> drawablesUrl = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
            try {
                for (ProductDetails objProDetails : result) {
                    drawablesUrl.add(Global
                            .getBitmapFromURL(objProDetails.image_path));
                    // drawablesUrl.add(loadImageFromURL(objProDetails.image_path));
                }
                return drawablesUrl;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Drawable loadImageFromURL(String image_path) {
            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                return d;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private String readJSONSFeed(String url, String productID) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + Constants.REQ_FOR_PRODUCT_IMAGE
                    + productID + Constants.REQ_FOR_OFFER);



            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                int statuscode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if (statuscode == 200) {

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line = null;
                    if ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }
                    // buffer.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                } else {
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private synchronized ArrayList<ProductDetails> processProductDetailsJSON(
                String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray Records = json
                        .getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_OBJECT_DATA);
                for (int i = 0; i < Records.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Record = Records.getJSONObject(i);

                    String tTitle = Record.getString("title");
                    String tImagePath = Record.getString("image_path");
                    String tDescription = Record.getString("description");

                    pDetails = new ProductDetails(tDescription, tTitle,
                            tImagePath);

                    if (pDetails == null) {
                    } else {
                        productList.add(pDetails);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
                return null;
            }

            return productList;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake you are doing while launching second activity:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProductsActivity.this,
                ProductDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("product", (Products) productObj.get(position));
//      startActivity(intent);
        View view = getLocalActivityManager()
                .startActivity("product",intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
    replaceView(view);
    }
```

### **Mistake**:

You are adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, it will clear your activity stack, instead you should put the next activity in just FRONT by adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag.

### Solution:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(ProductsActivity.this, ProductDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    View view= getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("product", intent).getDecorView();
    // Again, replace the view
    replaceView(view);
}
```